# Does there exist $a$ such that $p$ divides ${p^a n\choose k}$ for all $k=1,\ldots ,p^an-1$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

If $p$ is a prime number, then $p$ divides $\displaystyle{{p\choose k}}$ for all $k=1,\ldots ,p-1$, so the the set $S_{p,1}=\{ a\in \mathbb{N}|\; p\mid  \displaystyle{{p^a\choose k}} \, \text{for all $k=1,\ldots ,p^{a}-1$}\}$ is non-empty, namely $1\in S_{p,1}$. For $p$ a fixed prime and $n\geq 1$ a fixed integer with $\mathrm{gcd}(p,n)=1$, define the set $$ S_{p,n}=\{ a\in \mathbb{N},\; p\mid  {p^a n\choose k} \, \text{for all $k=1,\ldots ,p^an-1$}\}.$$
Is $S_{p,n}$ non-empty for $n>1$?

Just thought of this question while computing a certain sum, and I don't know how difficult or easy it is as I'm not a specialist.

Comment: The Lucas' and Kummer's theorems might be useful. Links: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem

Comment: Actually, Lucas's theorem implies that $S_{p,n}$ is nonempty iff $n=p^{k}$ for some nonnegative integer $k$.

Comment: @richrow would you write your comment as answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: @pigeon I just proved your binomial identity. Could you maybe undelete so that I may post my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, the Lucas's theorem implies that $S_{n,p}$ is nonempty if and only if $n$ is equal to $p^k$ for some nonnegative integer $k$. For more details see, for example, here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem